# Redirect to an error page when using Internet Explorer in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-5

I am looking for a way to redirect IE users to a special page were they will be told to upgrade their browser to Firefox or Chrome.

The best idea I have currently is to find the user browser with:

```
Request.UserAgent.contains("msie")
```

in the Global.asax in Application_AcquireRequestState and redirect the user with:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Shared/UpgradeBrowser");
```

Unfortunately this does not work and causes a redirect loop. 
Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to do this? Beyond "IE" being pretty vague (version 8 through 11 are all actively used), what problem are you trying to solve by dictating a user's browser usage? How will you handle "Project Spartan"/Edge, which will have a different user agent?

Comment: We are currently not supporting any IE version lower than 10, for ease of implementation. Actually this is quite common requesting the user to upgrade their browser.

Comment: So, you would prefer a user browse your site with Netscape Navigator rather than with IE9?

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is create simple BaseController that extends Controller and have all my other Controllers except for the ErrorController extend from the BaseController.

After that you can override the OnAuthorization method as shown below.

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
     if (userAgent.Contains("MSIE"))
         filterContext.Result = base.RedirectToAction("Upgrade", "Error")

     base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```